Custom rotate function based on spheroid
Basically if PostGIS had an ST_Rotate but for geography type where it calculated based on a spheroid. But in my case I want to do this in a QGIS plugin. I need to rotate polygons and I only ever need to rotate about the centroid of the polygon.
Would this solution work for rotating each point of the polygon:
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def rotate_point(center_lat, center_lon, point_lat, point_lon, rotation_angle_deg):
    geod = Geodesic.WGS84
    inv = geod.Inverse(center_lat, center_lon, point_lat, point_lon)
    distance = inv['s12']
    initial_bearing = inv['azi1']
    new_bearing = (initial_bearing + rotation_angle_deg) % 360
    direct = geod.Direct(center_lat, center_lon, new_bearing, distance)
    return direct['lat2'], direct['lon2']

If this does work then why does an ST_Rotate function for geography type not exist in PostGIS? What problems for rotation on a spheroid am I missing?

Maybe because one point inside a polygon can fall outside it when rotating both?
